# Метод WshShell.SendKeys в VBS некорректно вводит данные в cmd

Tags: cmd, windows-7, vbscript, telnet

Набросал скрипт vbs для удаленного подключения через cmd / telnet к роутеру, с имитацией набора логина и пароля через метод WshShell.SendKeys.

Логин вводится верно. Далее вводится пароль, но он перебрасывается на следующую строку вследствии чего вводится неверно.

**Тело скрипта:**

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next

Dim WshShell, theCalculator
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WScript.Echo("Reboot D-Link 2500u by Telnet (~45 sec)")
theCalculator = WshShell.Run("cmd /c telnet.exe", 1, False)

WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.AppActivate "%comspec%"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "set logfile tel2500.log~" 
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "open 192.168.1.1~"
WScript.Sleep 5500
WshShell.SendKeys "admin~"
WScript.Sleep 1500
WshShell.SendKeys "admin~"
WScript.Sleep 1500
WshShell.SendKeys "sysinfo~"
WScript.Sleep 1500
'WshShell.SendKeys "kill 1~"
WshShell.SendKeys "reboot~"
WScript.Sleep 37000

WshShell.AppActivate "%comspec%"
WshShell.SendKeys "xx"    
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "open 192.168.1.1~"
WScript.Sleep 1500
WshShell.SendKeys "admin~"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "admin~"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "sysinfo~"
WScript.Sleep 1500
WshShell.SendKeys "logout~"
WScript.Sleep 500

WshShell.SendKeys "xx"
WshShell.SendKeys "quit~"
```

В чем может быть проблема? Помогите.